# What is the difference between Atlas and Consensus health?

Tags: directory, server

Dear those experts who are familiar with Directory Protocol,
I just search on Atlas for Authorities Directories and found there are 10, include "[Tonga](https://atlas.torproject.org/#search/flag:authority)". But when I check the [Consensus Health](https://consensus-health.torproject.org/consensus-health.html) I found that "[Tonga](https://atlas.torproject.org/#details/4A0CCD2DDC7995083D73F5D667100C8A5831F16D)" is not on the list of "Signatures", "Known flags", "Number of relays voted about", "Consensus methods"; while the node named "consensus" did not appear in Atlas, but is on those list and can vote the "network status".
So may question is that:
Is "Tonga" really an Authority Directory?
IS "Tonga" and "consensus" a same node?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is because Tonga is a little special. Unlike the other directory authorities Tonga doesn't vote in the consensus (iirc it's the bridge authority). Take a peek at the following list...

https://gitweb.torproject.org/stem.git/tree/stem/descriptor/remote.py#n674

Note that Tonga doesn't have a v3ident. Tonga is an authority, but doesn't vote so for things like Consensus Health which are concerned with the consensus it's moot.

Comment: Thank you Damian for your quick response to my question. I think I got your point about "Tonga", but how about the node named "consensus" highlighted in blue? Is it just a virtual node designated for the final agreement between other nodes' votes?
thank you in advance!

Comment: Nope, 'consensus' isn't a relay. Directory authorities each vote on what they think should the network should look like. These individual votes are tallied, and the majority determines the 'consensus'. The consensus is the de-facto definition of who's a tor relay, and used by clients (tor users) to make their circuits. This is a way of distributing trust so a single malicious authority (or even a group of them) can't hurt users.